# Canon Pixma MX350 connection problem

Tags: printing, canon

I'm trying to make my Canon Pixma MX350 network printer work with Lubuntu 13.04 with Gnome Shell 3.8 (already went through the other questions for this model).

Cups (or the Gnome printer manager) can't find it on the network just by scanning. I managed to add the printer to Cups though by specifying the MAC address manually. Still it doesn't respond to print jobs. Cups says (or the printer is saying to Cups?):

> "cannot specify model number."

I've used the 32 bit driver on my 64 bit Lubuntu in the past, a much older driver though downloaded from Canon.
Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. So due to recent total refusal of the printer to respond, I removed it from the system and now I'm trying to reinstall it with a newer driver, from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-stable/+packages). Still 32 bit though as that repo doesn't have the 64bit flavour either.

This printer does accept print jobs though from Ubuntu and Windows on another machine on the same network. Ubuntu has it installed with the older driver. Here is a longer error log from Cups: http://pastie.org/8101197.
Now I went back to the old driver because it works on Ubuntu on the other pc. I also switched the printer connection from Wlan to wired LAN to exclude wireless flakiness. The Cups error message then turns into:

> "cannot load library"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a setup that works on all my systems now, Ubuntu or Windows:
1.) I use the older 32bit-driver ver. 3.30 that is also available directly from Canon.
2.) The new router from my ISP has a USB port, which the old one didn't.
Hooking up the Canon to the router via USB (not wlan, not ethernet) made everything work, even if the Canon is turned on only after submitting the print job!

Answer (score 1):

I also had a "cannot specify model number" error.
Turned out, the printer driver was from Canon package (cnijfilter), however, the printer description (PPD) was from GutenPrint package - they are incompatible.

Fixed by changing the PPD file to the one from Canon (Printer properties -> Make and Model -> Change, then select the appropriate driver - mine was called "MG4200 Ver 3.90").